# php7 strict_types - and scalar type hinting - stop method caller casting float to int

Tags: php, types, casting

My classes are auto-loaded via composer.

a.php

```
<?php

$b = new B;
echo $b->add(1.5, 2.5);
```

b.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class B()
{
    public function add(int $a, int $b):int
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

The output is 3.

If I add the `declare(strict_types=1);` to the top of `a.php`, then I get an error. This means that PHP will cast the float to an integer unless every file that calls `B->add()` has the `declare(strict_types=1);`. I do not want to have to declare strict_types everywhere. this could be incompatible with the rest of `a.php`.

What I think I should be able to do is: is that if I have `declare(strict_types=1);` at the top of `b.php`. Then any time the class B is instantiated, the strict typing is enforced.

Is there a way of enforcing this?

So the rule I want to enforce is: wherever B is instantiated, `add` should only ever accept an integer, and the caller should NEVER do any casting.

Any normal language will cause an error if you try to pass a float into a method which expects an integer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(add(1.5, 2.5))
}

func add(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

// Output
main.go:6: constant 1.5 truncated to integer
main.go:6: constant 2.5 truncated to integer
```

Comment: from docs "Strict typing applies to function calls made from within the file with strict typing enabled, not to the functions declared within that file. If a file without strict typing enabled makes a call to a function that was defined in a file with strict typing, the caller's preference (weak typing) will be respected, and the value will be coerced."

Comment: I don't know what "normal language" means exactly but PHP is and has always been loosely typed and proud. An [early proposal of scalar type hinting](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hinting_with_cast) didn't pass through because it didn't play well with this philosophy. Of course, this is a pretty good question and I absolutely understand your use case.

Comment: PaulCrovella, bxN5 - Aware of your comments. However I am looking for a way to enforce. e.g. let's suppose b takes money in pence. I don't want a user to be able to put £10.50 into the method, and PHP converts that to 10p.

Comment: @Gravy so use strict_types everywhere